# CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES not set on Linux when setting CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to a config

Tags: linux, cmake

I am running the following to configure my project: `$ cmake -G Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug path/to/cmake/file`. Then, I do  `message(STATUS ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})` in my `CMake` files and the output is nothing.

I don't beliebe there is a problem with the way that I am passing the build type since when I run `make`, the `G`flag has been added. Seems like everything works besides setting `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`. This is on Ubuntu 18.04. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES be populated? It should be empty. Or have a value if you configure it.

Comment: As I see, the core question is "Whether the Eclipse project created is **multi-configuration** or not". The variable `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` is set by *multi-configuration* generators, but is left empty by *single-configuration* ones. Googling reveals [some SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654026/cmake-eclipse-build-configurations), which tells that given generator creates *single-configuration* project. But there are some other, unanswered posts, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384292/building-release-and-debug-targets-at-once-for-eclipse-cdt-with-cmake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Damn this is like the 5th time you help me in the last month. Thanks for helping me out!